# when seller in the dashbard it can create new product. when buyer comes i only want to show index and show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Here is my route.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

 devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations'}#, confirmations: 'users/confirmations' }
  root 'home#homepage'
  get 'dashboard', to: 'home#dashboard'
end
```

Here is the product controller

```
  class ProductsController < InheritedResources::Base

  private

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, images: [])
    end

end
```

Here is the product model

```
 class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :images
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :price, presence: true
    validate :image_type

    private
     def image_type
        if images.attached? ==false
            errors.add(:images, " are missing")
        end
     end
    end
```

Here is the user model

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
 validates :email, format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i, message: "Email invalid"  },
   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 254 }
   has_many :products
   
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  
   enum role: { Buyer: 0, Seller: 1 } 
   devise :registerable, :confirmable
end
```

In the the views home folder dashboard.

```
     <h1>Dashboard</h1>

 <%= link_to "Product", products_path %>
```

I uses scaffold that seller can perform crud operations and add multiple images..Now when buyer see seller product I want him they see only index and show action